# Javascript regex - specific number of characters in unordered string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test whether or not an unordered string has '3' in it 5 times.

For example:

```
var re = /3{5}/;
re.test("333334"); //returns true as expected
re.test("334333"); //returns false since there is no chain of 5 3s
```

What regex would make the second line return true? If regex is not the best way to test this, what is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
(str.match(/3/g) || []).length >= 5
```

Or

```
str.split(3).length > 5
```

Where `str` is the string you want to test.

Comment: It should be `str.split('3')` (with the quotes). Fixed for you.

Comment: @SashaChedygov Quotes are not necessary. From [ES5 spec Section 15.5.4.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14), at step 8, "*If `separator` is a `RegExp` object (its `[[Class]]` is "`RegExp`"), let `R = separator`; otherwise let `R = ToString(separator)`.*"

Comment: @Oriol: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know that. I'd still prefer the quotes, but that's just me. :)

Comment: @SashaChedygov Also note that the `split` way needs `>` instead of `>=`, because it counts an additional item: `''.split(3).length === 1`, `'3'.split(3).length === 2`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can write this:

```
var re = /(?:3[^3]*){5}/;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to regexp and am having trouble understanding capture parentheses. According the the MDN, this would match '3[^3]*' but not remember the match. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @Ativ: yes `(?:...)` are non-capturing parenthesis. The goal is only to group, to be able to put the `{5}` quantifier in factor. A capturing group will store the content to be reuse later (with a backreference). But it is not needed here. Using non-capturing group use obviously less memory, and is a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for

```
s.replace(/[^3]/,'').length >= 5
```

Assuming that the string to be tested is named `s`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
string.indexOf('33333') > -1
```